# streaming video is playing, when voice input enable the video change to silence,how to fix this bug?

Tags: ios, audio, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

Please check the image, I add the following code when voide input finish, but it doesn't work. Once the voice input finish, the video would have sound after a short while, but sometimes not, don't know why. Any solution?

```
    /**
 *  back from other audio app or use voice input
 */
- (void)enableAudio {
//    AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
//    UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
//    AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,sizeof(sessionCategory),&sessionCategory);
//    AudioSessionSetActive(YES);

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
}
```

Comment: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/268339     this is the correct link

Comment: I'd edit your image in, but it's behind a login form.